# Plotly/ Dash: Line connects "backwards"

Tags: python, plotly, line, plotly-dash

I am trying to display the value of a variable over time with Plotly/Dash:

```
fig =  px.scatter(p, x = 'charttime' , y = 'value', color = 'label')
fig.update_traces(mode= 'markers+lines')
fig.update_layout(
    yaxis_title = 'value (' + p.iloc[0]['valueuom'] +')',
    xaxis_title = 'time'
)
```

This is the result I am getting:

[image]

The last line connects a point later in time to an earlier point, but this does not make sense in this context. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing the structure of your data. But my best guess is that you may have time in the wrong format, or you have it ordered as a factor and it was in the wrong order.

Comment: https://community.plotly.com/t/time-series-scatter-lines-connecting-non-sequentially-jumbled-lines/26721 this could be the thing that is causing your issue

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: as per other comments investigate a) sorting of dataframe b) datatypes not being datetime hence sort being alpha-numeric

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments. The dataframe just had to be sorted by the time field.